# C++ using new to create object array with initializer

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

I wrote a class, something like this (just for demonstration) :

```
class cls{
public:
    cls(int a):value(a){}
private:
    int value;
};
```

And I want to dynamically create an array, each element initialized to a specific value like 2:

```
cls *arr = new cls[N](2);
```

But g++ reported 'error: parenthesized initializer in array new'.

I searched the Internet, but only to find similar questions about basic types like `int`  and `double`, and answer is NO WAY.

Suppose the class must be initialized, how to solve the problem? Do I have to abandon constructer?

Comment: Use a vector. You should be using one anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

```
cls *arr = new cls[3] { 2, 2, 2 };
```

If you use `std::vector`, you can:

```
std::vector<cls> v(3, cls(2));
```

or

```
std::vector<cls> v(3, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried vector and use constructor to print a string at the same time. The string shows only once, but I checked every element is initialized. Seems vector only initializes once, then copy the one to the remaining objects.

Comment: @Twisx constructor called when you used `cls(2)` manually and passed it to vector initialisation. Then copy constructor used to fill elements.

Answer (score 5):

Use a vector.

If you *insist* on using a dynamically allocated array instead of `std::vector`, you have to do it the hard way: allocate a block of memory for the array, and then initialize all the elements one by one. **Don't** do this unless you really can't use a vector! This is only shown for educational purposes.

```
cls* arr = static_cast<cls*>(::operator new[](N*sizeof(cls)));
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    ::new (arr+i) cls(2);
}
// ::delete[] arr;
```

Comment: Thanks, vector is enough for me.

Comment: Thank you for this obscure answer.  It came in very handy for me in my use case:  I needed a pointer to an array of objects that lack a default constructor to be queued to another thread which will later destroy the memory when it's no longer needed.  I wouldn't have been able to do that with a vector.  I'll admit it's less pretty, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use vectors

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class cls{
public:
    cls(int a):value(a){}
private:
    int value;
};

int main() {

vector<cls> myArray(100, cls(2));

return 0;
}
```

That creates a vector (an array) with 100 cls objects initialized with 2;

Comment: Thanks. I tried vector and use constructor to print a string at the same time. The string shows only once, but I checked every element is initialized.