# C++ nested struct with dynamic array in healer file

Tags: c++, struct

I'm trying to define a bunch of structs in a header file. For example:

```
struct Firststruct{
    int useless;
};

struct Secondstruct{
    Firststruct* struct1;    // we want to have a dynamic array here.    
};

struct Thirdstruct{
    Secondstruct* struct2;    // we want to have a dynamic array here.    
};
```

And for simple usage in main or source file. We want to define the struct constructor. For example:

```
struct Secondstruct{
    Firststruct* struct1;    // we want to have a dynamic array here. 

    // constructor
    Secondstruct(int num_struct1){
        struct1 = new Firststruct[num_struct1];
    };

    // deconstructor
    blablabla
};
```

So here is the question, how could we define the constructor in Thridstruct?

```
struct Thirdstruct{
    Secondstruct* struct2;    // we want to have a dynamic array here. 

    // constructor
    Thirdstruct(int num_struct2){
        struct2 = new Secondstruct[num_struct2];    // this of couse does not work. 
    };

    // deconstructor
    blablabla
};
```

I am new in C++, so I do not know how to write it. Could someone provide some ideas?

Thanks. :)

Comment: @ArminMontigny No. And by posting your answer as a comment you've dodged peer review so I cannot downvote your wrong answer to mark it as wrong for others. Please don't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object array initialization without default constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754763/object-array-initialization-without-default-constructor)

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/q/24924434/4386278

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1: make `Secondstruct` default constructible by defining a default constructor.

Option 2: do not create a dynamic array of `Secondstruct` directly, but instead a dynamic array of raw bytes of sufficient size. Then reuse the storage with `std::uninitialized_fill`.

Best option: Use `std::vector` instead which does the complicated sounding thing of option 2 as well as lacks the memory leaks and undefined behaviour that the custom attempt of implementing dynamic array is undoubtedly going to suffer from.